# 15 Puzzle A* Alguns casos não funcionam

Tags: java, inteligência-artificial

Estou a tentar implementar o algoritmo A Star para resolver o problema do 15-puzzle no entanto existem alguns que correm por tempo infinito sem resolver o problema.

por exemplo o input(o de cima é o inicial e o de baixo o objectivo) que deveria dar no output "56" movimentos :

> 2F1C856B49A73ED0
>   123456789ABCDEF0

Outros casos de 56 movimentos funcionam perfeitamente mas este não

```
public class AStar {

static class State {
    private Ilayout layout;
    private State father;
    private double g;
    private int h;
    public State(Ilayout l, State n) {
        layout = l;
        father = n;
        if (father!=null){
            g = father.g + l.getG();
            h= l.getH();
        }
        else g = 0.0;
    }
    public String toString() { return layout.toString(); }
    public double getG() {return g;}
    public double getH() {return h;}
}

protected Queue<State> abertos;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private List<State> fechados;
private State actual;
private Ilayout objective;

final private List<State> sucessores(State n) {
    List<State> sucs = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Ilayout> children = n.layout.children(objective);

    for(Ilayout e: children) {
        if (n.father == null || !e.equals(n.father.layout)){
            State nn = new State(e, n);
            sucs.add(nn);
        }
    }

    return sucs;
}


final public Iterator<State> solve(Ilayout s, Ilayout goal) {
    objective = goal;
    Queue<State> abertos = new PriorityQueue<>(10,(s1, s2) -> (int) Math.signum((s1.getG()+s1.getH())-(s2.getG()+s2.getH())) );//Queue<Integer> responsta = new PriorityQueue<>(10,(s1, s2) -> (int) Math.signum(s1-s2) );
    List<State> A = new ArrayList<>();
    abertos.add(new State(s, null));
    List<State> sucs;
    Hashtable<String,Integer> a = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    a.put(abertos.peek().layout.getBoard(), 0);
    if(abertos.peek().layout.isGoal(objective)  ) {
        A.add(actual);
        return A.listIterator();
    }
    try {
        while (true) {
            if(abertos.isEmpty()) return null;
            actual = abertos.remove();
            a.put(actual.layout.getBoard(), (int) actual.getG());
            if (actual.layout.isGoal(objective)) {
                A.add(actual);
                return A.iterator();
            }
            else {
                if(actual.getG()+actual.getH()<81){
                    sucs = this.sucessores(actual);
                    for (int i = 0; i < sucs.size(); i++) {
                        if (!a.containsKey(sucs.get(i).layout.getBoard())) {
                            abertos.add(sucs.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(OutOfMemoryError E) {
        return null;
    }
}}
```